# how to develop android soft keyboard example with a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-softkeyboard

I have done a database for the suggestion words
but where to put it into the android soft keyboard example and how to use the words from db in the program? so that I will not need to type the word completely and it will shown the suggestion word in database

Answer (score 1):

Inside the SDK check out the Samples folder, this contains a soft keyboard example and more information on how to suggest results.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the soft keyboard example. But I cannot analyze the whole coding well and I do not know how to do to add my suggestion words

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle database in SoftKeyboard.java Class.

Answer (score 0):

To get the suggestion words from .db, please use **SQLiteOpenHelper** or **SQLiteAssetsHelper**.

To show the suggestion words in candidate view, please modify the updateCandidates() method of SoftKeyboard.java file in Google SoftKeyboard example project.

```
/**
 * Update the list of available candidates from the current composing
 * text.  This will need to be filled in by however you are determining
 * candidates.
 */
private void updateCandidates() {
    if (!mCompletionOn) {
        // mComposing is current text you typed.
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            // Get suggested words list from your database here.
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(mComposing.toString());

            // This method will show the list as suggestion. 
            setSuggestions(list, true, true);
        } else {
            setSuggestions(null, false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

To enter the picked word from candidate view to input text, please modify following method in SoftKeyboard example project.

```
public void pickSuggestionManually(int index) {
    if (mCompletionOn && mCompletions != null && index >= 0
            && index < mCompletions.length) {
        CompletionInfo ci = mCompletions[index];
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitCompletion(ci);
        if (mCandidateView != null) {
            mCandidateView.clear();
        }
        updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
    } else if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
        // If we were generating candidate suggestions for the current
        // text, we would commit one of them here.  But for this sample,
        // we will just commit the current text.
        commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
        // You need to add getter method for suggested words shown in candidate view
    }
}
```